# Why does epylint ignore RCI msgs and how to change?

Tags: python, emacs, pylint

In using pylint in emacs, the instructions are to use the epylint script. It seems like the epylint script calls pylint with `--disable-msg-cat=CRI` to disable some messages. Why does epylint disable C and R (I'm ok with disabling I) but I think R and C are generally useful. How do I enable these or should I write my own epylint script?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just edit the script for whatever level you prefer?

Comment: There is a `pylint` package in melpa, with a `pylint-options` variable that you can customize.

Comment: "epylint" stands for "Error"pylint, it's a quick that makes it easier to integrate in editor for "quick" feedback on your code, hence the deactivation. You may still use pylint itself or use existing pylint wrappers for emacs